# How to not see background when container overflow-y is auto & container is not overflowing

Tags: html, css

I was wondering how I can not see the orange background when there isn't enough  in the  to make the item-container overflow. So, if I put 4 divs in there, it wont over flow and you will see orange to the right, but if you add one more item to my example, a horizontal scrollbar will appear and cover the orange background on the right. I want the
item background to cover the whole item-container even if item-container doesn't have a scrollbar

[image]

[Image with scrollbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byNzo.png)

```css
/* Copyright 2014 Owen Versteeg; MIT licensed */

body {
  background: rgba(25, 25, 25, 255)
}

#header-text {
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

#header-text2 {
  color: blue;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.item-container {
  background: orange;
  width: 418px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1 id="header-text">Hello</h1>
  <h3 id="header-text2">Hello</h3>

  <div class="item-container">
    <div class="item">Item1</div><div class="item">Item1</div><div class="item">Item2</div><div class="item">Item2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, make your `.item-container` have no background:

```
    .item-container {
      width: 418px;
      height: 100px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      overflow-y: auto;
    }
```

Or have your items take up the full-width using flex like so:

```css
.item-container{
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  
}

.item{
  background-color: yellow;
  flex-grow:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="item-container">
    <div class="item">Item1</div><div class="item">Item1</div><div class="item">Item2</div><div class="item">Item2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should show the markup for your flexbox solution here, in your answer.

Comment: Thanks, solution is good, can add flex-wrap: wrap to get my desired goal

Answer (score 0):

Your layout is troublesome. Rather than pixel-perfect scrollbar gaps, why not set your inner blocks to 25% or use flexbox?

```
.item {
  width: 25%;
  ...
}
```

Comment: This will only work if there is min 4 item, not 3...

Comment: I think the issue was specifically when there are exactly four items. OP doesn't mind the background when there are fewer.